# Can't make Vue.js transition work properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, transition

I have a list of items displayed via `v-for`. By default only the summary part of each item shows up. When clicking on an item, the details part of the item is displayed.

This is accomplished by adding/removing an `active` class, and toggling `display: block` / `display: none` on the item's details part.

Now I want to add smooth transitions. I followed [the first example in the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html). But I can't figure out how to make it work as expected. Currently the transition doesn't work at all: the details part appears instantly when clicking on the item, and disappears instantly when clicking again.

What's wrong with my code?

```css
    .event-details {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .event.active .event-details-enter-active,
    .event.active .event-details-leave-active {
      transition: opacity .5s;
      transition: height .5s;
    }
    
    .event.active .event-details-enter,
    .event.active .event-details-leave-to {
      opacity: 0;
      display: none;
      height: 0;
    }
    
    .event.active .event-details-enter,
    .event.active .event-details-leave-to {
      opacity: 1;
      display: block;
      height: auto;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<li :class="{ active: event.active }" v-for="event in events" @click="showEvent(event)">
      <div class="event-summary">
        content
      </div>
      <transition name="event-details">
        <div class="event-details">
          content
        </div>
      </transition>
    </li>
```

EDIT: here's a `console.log` of the events array:

[image]

Comment: did you read about https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions`?

Comment: I'm not trying to apply transitions to list items, only to a particular element that happens to be inside a list item element.

Comment: please share your data object or a running example

Comment: If by that you mean the `events` array, I just added it to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `v-if` directive to the element wrapped by the `transition` as follows

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      events: [{
          active: false,
          city: "new york"
        },
        {
          active: false,
          city: "Algiers"
        },
        {
          active: false,
          city: "Paris"
        },
        {
          active: false,
          city: "Madrid"
        },

      ]
    };

  },
  methods: {
    showEvent(index) {
      this.events[index].active = !this.events[index].active;
    }

  }

})
```

```css
.event-details{
padding:20px;
color:#55ff44
}
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all .8s ease;
}
.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}
.slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-to
/* .slide-fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li :class="{ active: event.active }" v-for="(event,index) in events" @click="showEvent(index)">
      <div class="event-summary">
        {{event.city}}
      </div>
      <transition name="slide-fade">
        <div class="event-details" v-if='event.active'>
          some content
        </div>
      </transition>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```